# Programmatically update a field's value

Tags: 8

I want to update a node field's value when a node is updated.

Tried using the code mentioned here [Programmatically updating a node Drupal 8](http://dropbucket.org/node/7270)

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

    function hello_world_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {

      $check = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

      if ($check) {
      $node = Node::load($check->nid->value);
      $node->title->value = 'testing';     //set value for field
      $node->save();
      }
    }
```

but it did not work. I get a 500 error after saving the node. I also tried taking out the if statement and specifying a node id `$node = Node::load(1);`

I also tried using [Update a node / Entity programmatically in Drupal 8](http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/65/update-a-node-entity-programmatically-drupal-8)

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;


function hello_world_node_update(Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {

$node = Node::load(1);
$node->set("title", 'New value'); // also tried $node->setTitle('The new Title');
$node->save();

}
```

but no luck either.

In addition, I tried using different hooks entity_presave, entity_update, node_update, but did not make any difference.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
function MODULE_NAME_node_presave(Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  $node->setTitle('new Title');
  $node->set('body', 'this is body');
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This is another variation with using the hook you originally tried to use.

I think the problem with your code is that you try to load a new instance of the node, but you should use the node that is provided as paramater `$entity`:

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

function hello_world_entity_presave(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity)   {
  if ($entity instanceof NodeInterface) {
    $entity->title->value = 'testing';     //set value for field
    // $entity->save(); (not needed)
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Added the use statement to the code.

Comment: just tried your code, but it's breaking the site, getting the classic `The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.`

Comment: This code is only to demonstrate how to use the hook. You need the right use statements. You can find this out, if you look in watchdog (/admin/reports/dblog).

Comment: adding `use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;` code no longer auto breaks the site, but after saving the node, I get the 500 error like I was getting in my question and the logs is not logging anything about it.

Comment: I only wanted to point at the problem: Don't load a new instance of the node, but use the one provided as function parameter. What error is behind 500? Please check your log files or switch on error logging.

Comment: I clear the log, so I don't get confused with all the other previous errors, but after saving and getting the error multiple times [log files are empty](http://i.stack.imgur.com/69QDE.jpg)

Comment: You will have a hard time debugging this without error logging. Did you check your php settings? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er)

Comment: I found the second problem. In the presave hook we don't need to save. We only change the object. I remove this from the code.

Comment: great ✓ works now.

Comment: Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList has no effect , How to get rid of this notice ??

Comment: Note that when not in the `preSave` context, you do indeed need to run `$entity->save()` after setting the field (such as from a custom module update hook).

Answer (score 4):

Titles in Drupal 8 are not set like standard fields; they have their own function. Use `$node->setTitle('New Title');` for a node or `$entity->setLabel('New Title');` for a generic entity. See [Node::setTitle](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AsetTitle/8.3.x) for more info.